# Testing react context with jest and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to set up tests for my `component App.js` that takes in a `context` as a prop and returns a provider. The issue is when I am trying to test it, the context that I pass into it always resolves to undefined.

I put a console log in the component and and one between creating the context and creating the Component (which should receive context as a param). This resulted in the console.log in the component first for some reason. This is probably why I am getting context is undefined as it hasn't been initialized yet.

```js
// Component/Provider
const App = (props) => {
  const {children, context} = props;
  const {data, dispatch} = useReducer(reducer);
  console.log(context); //undefined and this console.log runs first
  return <context.Provider value={useCallback(dispatch)}>{children}</context.Provider>
}
```

In my test.js

```js
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-testing-library';
import {App} from './App';
const context = React.createContext();

function Provider(children) {
  console.log(context); //Is correct but runs second
  return <App Context={context}>{children}</App>;
}

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: Provider, ...options });

const Consumer = () => {
  const dispatch = useContext(context);
  returns <Button onClick={dispatch({type: 'Do something'})}>Whatever</Button/>;
}
customRender(<Consumer />)
```

I should be able to pass a `Context` into my component to create the provider but its always undefined.

Comment: I believe you have already found that your component expects `context` prop but `Context` is passed. casing matters.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck for a bit before finding out how to proceed. My problem was that I wasn't crating the **right shape** for the context : I was giving it some props but not the one passed in my **real context**. So the component couldn't browse that new shape.

Here was my prod shape (non test)

```
export default React.createContext({
  authenticationInfos: {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {
      id: "",
      email: "",
      roles: []
    },
    customer: {
      id: "",
      prenom: "",
      nom: "",
      tel: "",
      adress: "",
      postalCode: "",
      town: "",
      sellRequests: []
    }
  },
  setAuthenticationInfos: value => {}
});
```

And I was just passing what was inside **authenticationInfos**, but not the prop **authenticationInfos** itself, and I was also forgetting the **setAuthenticationInfos** prop.

Here is my test component that works with context hook :

Function from the [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context) documentation

```
const customRender = (ui, { providerProps, ...renderOptions }) => {
  return render(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={providerProps}>{ui}</AuthContext.Provider>,
    renderOptions
  );
};

describe("<ConnectModal>", () => {
  test("should be able to access auth context", () => {
    const providerProps = {
      authenticationInfos: {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {
          id: "",
          email: "",
          roles: [],
        },
        customer: {
          id: "",
          prenom: "",
          nom: "",
          tel: "",
          adress: "",
          postalCode: "",
          town: "",
          sellRequests: [],
        },
        shop: {
          appToken: 54,
        },
      },
      setAuthenticationInfos: (value) => {},
    };
    customRender(<MKMConnectModal />, { providerProps });
    // expect(screen.getByText(/^My Name Is:/)).toHaveTextContent(
    //   "My Name Is: C3P0"
    // );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a typo, but is your file really called `test.js`?
If so, you will need to change it to `.jsx`, as you're using JSX in your test (e. g. in the `Provider` component).